# How does video come on the walls of the buildings?

Tags: now-you-see-me

In the movie "[Now You See Me](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1670345/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1)", The video is shown on the walls of the building. How did they do this?

[image]

Comment: Just an FYI tidbit, this is similar to what they used during the queens jubilee celebration when the band was performing and the scenes were projected on the building like a live music video if you will.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Taking into account that everything *magic* in the movie was actually *not*, and that there was an extensive use of gadgetry by *The Eye*; the obvious answer to this question would be - *technology*. Or to be more precise - *projectors*, *holographic displays* of some sort. Earlier in the movie, when the Horsemen are first summoned, we see a holographic projection created using four projectors planted in the room.

[image: the safe]

Also, at the last show, we can see them standing in front of a projection generator (the glowing circle like stands). So what all this is supposed to explain, is that it is an incredibly clever use of lights and holographs that make it possible to create such illusions. (*please don't go for scientific plausibility on this one*)

Comment: I think there were only three projectors.

Comment: I think there were four - each activated by one of them.

Comment: There were only three projectors all activated by Woody touching the light bulb.

Answer (score 0):

Actually that's just using 3D/4D projections. Pretty cool technology, been around a few years now. [Here is a fun example.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5FXpIVnkKzg)

Comment: That youtube video doesn't show any 3D projection, just a 2D projection of a 3D scene...

Comment: Good point, that's what I was going for.

Comment: No problem :) You can only send 2D (light) images from a projector.